# Button has no reference Razor Page MVC

Tags: c#, html, razor, reference

I have made a full website and everything is working fine, but one button is killing me. It's a bit shamy because i think it's a very stupid mistake....

So this is my html button:

```
<button type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" id="sendenButton" onclick="sendenButton_Click">Senden</button>
```

and this the c# for the button:

```
protected void sendenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      SendMessage();
      Console.WriteLine(SendMessage().Content.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

I can't find out why my button onclick doesn't hit the c# function... 
I tried to register an event handler, but that doesn't work too, so hopefully you can help me out. Thank you

Perhaps you need to know that I do this in MVC Razor Page.

Comment: "Razor Page" as in ASP.net core Razor Pages, or Razor views in an ASP.net MVC application? The way you have it currently is more how WebForms would work

Comment: Is it ASP.NET MVC Application? MVC application does not have code behind, so there are not server controls and there is nothing like event handlers in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: As an aside, you are calling `SendMessage` twice in that event handler.  I don't know if you intended that or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button type="submit" runat="server" class="btn btn-default" id="sendenButton" onclick="sendenButton_Click">Senden</button>
```

This code represents a piece of web content. It's replacement for:

```
protected void sendenButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   try
   {
      SendMessage();
      Console.WriteLine(SendMessage().Content.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception) { }
}
```

Because this is obviously WebForms code. Which is a completely different thing from web development in MVC.

MVC works with a Model a View and a Controller (hence MVC). Your view (the button) communicaties with a Controller and sends data to that controller in a model. So try to delete the WebForms button and use the Razor page instead.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now i know whats wrong, i will try to get this in razor and hopefully it will work, only this button is needed to finish the site ...